# Match an element from list with lsreach

Tags: tcl

I have list in one variable let's say `var1`. I am performing `foreach`.
During the `foreach` it takes one variable at time, & I would like to check whether `foreach` variable if in the `var1` list or not with `lsearch`.

I have done it with if-else nesting, but if there are more cases to include like `var2`, `var3`, etc.. for other test cases, it becomes nest of lot of if-else.

How can I do it with `lsearch` because seems to easy as if any element is exist in the list then perform some task if not leave it.

```
foreach line $data {
    if {[lsearch -exact [file tail $line] $var1] >= 0}
        puts "got it"
    }
}
```

Above will be true only if I have one element in `var1` (only one variable in list), How can I check if more than one element in the list. With `lindex`?

Comment: The order of `[lsearch]` arguments is incorrect. First, there should be the list, then the string to search.

Comment: Oh, then I think it solved problem. It looks into the list first with the variable in foreach.  Like: [lsreach -exact $var1 [file tail $line]], that's working. Thanks...!!!

Comment: if it is answered, please close the question.